# How to save current scroll position for RecyclerView on item deletes?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a chat RecyclerView, I want to prevent RecyclerView from auto scrolling to last item on item deleted. I want to make the smooth scroll only on activity starts.
Below, a code samples for setting up the RecyclerView and the message deleting process.
If anyone can help me. Thank you...

Setting RecyclerView

```
private fun setRecyclerView() {
        val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        linearLayoutManager.stackFromEnd = true
        recyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
        //recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
        adapter = SingleChatAdapter(this, messages, senderRoom!!, receiverRoom!!, {num ->
            incDecNum(num)
        }) {show, hide ->
            showChosenToolbar(show, hide)
        }
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    }
```

Delete Message

```
private fun delBtn() {
        val delS = containerView?.findViewById<View>(R.id.deleteSelections)
        delS?.setOnClickListener {
            val senderDel = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.sender_deletes, null)
            val receiverDel = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.receiver_deletes, null)
            for (msg: SingleChatData in messages) {
                if (msg.selected && msg.senderId == auth.uid) {
                    val deleteDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(senderDel)
                        .setTitle("Delete This message")
                    val myDialog = deleteDialog?.show()
                    senderDel.deleteForMeS.setOnClickListener {
                        deleteForMe()
                        myDialog?.dismiss()
                        showChosenToolbar(false, true)
                        chosenNumTxt.text = "0"
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                    senderDel.deleteForAllS.setOnClickListener {
                        deleteForAll()
                        myDialog?.dismiss()
                        showChosenToolbar(false, true)
                        chosenNumTxt.text = "0"
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                    senderDel.cancelDeletionS.setOnClickListener { myDialog?.dismiss() }
                } else if (msg.selected && msg.senderId != auth.uid) {
                    val deleteDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(receiverDel)
                        .setTitle("Delete This message")
                    val myDialog = deleteDialog?.show()
                    receiverDel.deleteForMeR.setOnClickListener {
                        deleteForMe()
                        myDialog?.dismiss()
                        showChosenToolbar(false, true)
                        chosenNumTxt.text = "0"
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                    receiverDel.cancelDeletionR.setOnClickListener { myDialog?.dismiss() }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Add data to adapter

```
private fun setDataToAdapter(){
        firestore.collection("Chats").document(senderRoom!!).collection("messages").orderBy("time")
            .addSnapshotListener { value, _ ->
                if (!value?.isEmpty!!) {
                    messages.clear()
                    for (document in value.documents) {
                        val coMsg = document.data?.get("message").toString()
                        val coId = document.data?.get("senderId").toString()
                        val msgId = document.id
                        //Using Date
                        // Get Calendar
                        val calendarMap = document.data?.get("date") as Map<*, *>
                        val curTimestamp = calendarMap["time"] as com.google.firebase.Timestamp
                        val millis = curTimestamp.seconds * 1000 + curTimestamp.nanoseconds / 1000000
                        val ss = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault())
                        val netCal = Date(millis)
                        val msgTime = ss.format(netCal).toString()
                        // Get Day
                        val chatDay = document.data?.get("day").toString()
                        // Get Full Date
                        val fullDateStamp = calendarMap["time"] as com.google.firebase.Timestamp
                        val dateInMillis = fullDateStamp.seconds * 1000 + fullDateStamp.nanoseconds / 1000
                        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
                        val netAllDate = Date(dateInMillis)
                        val fullDate = sdf.format(netAllDate).toString()
                        val type = document.data?.get("type").toString()
                        val coMsgT = SingleChatData(coMsg, coId, msgId, msgTime, chatDay, fullDate, type)
                        messages.add(coMsgT)
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    recyclerView.post { // Call smooth scroll
                        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.itemCount - 1)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `notifyDataSetChanged()` (which basically says *"redisplay everything because **something somewhere** has changed in some way"*) you should use one of the more specific *notify* methods, like `notifyItemRemoved`. That way the Adapter and RecylerView can be smarter about visually updating, like avoiding scrolling and adding animations.

If you're talking about that `smoothScrollToPosition` call you're making, that looks like it happens whenever your data updated - and if I had to guess, I'd assume you're doing those updates in `deleteForMe()` and `deleteForAll()`. In which case, smooth scrolling to the last item is what you've told it to do. If you want to avoid that, and it's really only something that should happen *once* during setup, just add a flag or something:

```
// some top level / ViewModel property
var firstScrollDone = false

...

// in your data snapshot listener
if (!firstScrollDone) {
    firstScrollDone = true
    // do the scroll
}
```

There's probably a better way to do it in your specific situation, but you get the idea!

Comment: I tried this, but still the same thing. The scroll happens every deletion process.

Comment: @MahmoudNabil if that's the line causing the scroll (you can comment it out to make sure nothing else is making the scroll happen) then you just have to work out a way to do it on startup but not any other time. In that example, `firstScrollDone` is a top-level variable in the Activity - it's initialised to false when the Activity is created, and then set to true when the first scroll happens. And that scroll call will never happen again after that, because `firstScrollTrue` is always true - until the Activity is recreated. You just need to use that kind of approach